# css table : first column with fixed width

Tags: css, tabular

I'm trying to create a css table.
This was working fine, until I started to set a fixed width for the first column.

So basically I have:

```
<div class="table" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell" style="display:flex;align-items:center;min-width: 180px;max-width:180px;">Type</div>
            <div class="table-cell">Motif</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col3</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col4</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col5</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col6</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col7</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col8</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
        <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="input in vm.inputs">
            <div class="table-cell" ng-mouseover="vm.hoverIn(input)" ng-mouseleave="vm.hoverOut(input)" style="display:flex;align-items:center;min-width: 180px;max-width:180px;">
                {{input.type}}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.reason}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.cim10}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.start | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.end | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{vm.computeDays(input.start, input.end)}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.pending}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.details}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.comments}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
div.table {
    display: table;
}

div.table > div.thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

div.table > div.tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

div.table > div.thead > div.table-row,
div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

    div.table > div.thead > div.table-row > div.table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }

    div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row > div.table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        height: 42px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Now, the result is this:

[image: incorrect layout]

As you can see the second column is no more aligned with the first one.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, there is nothing wrong with using `<table>` for tabular data, and it certainly looks like you have tabular data. There certainly could be valid reasons for using CSS tables here but don't discard tables out of hand here.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I'm Learning css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not the fixed `width`, but the `display: flex;` you're adding inline, it's overriding `display: table-cell;`.

You might want to use `display: flex;` in the inner content of your tab.

```css
div.table {
    display: table;
}

div.table > div.thead {
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

div.table > div.tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

div.table > div.thead > div.table-row,
div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

    div.table > div.thead > div.table-row > div.table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }

    div.table > div.tbody > div.table-row > div.table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        height: 42px;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell" style="min-width: 100px;max-width:180px;">Type</div>
            <div class="table-cell">Motif</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col3</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col4</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col5</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col6</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col7</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col8</div>
            <div class="table-cell">col9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
        <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="input in vm.inputs">
            <div class="table-cell" ng-mouseover="vm.hoverIn(input)" ng-mouseleave="vm.hoverOut(input)" style="min-width: 100px;max-width:180px;">
                {{input.type}}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.reason}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.cim10}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.start | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.end | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{vm.computeDays(input.start, input.end)}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.pending}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.details}}</div>
            <div class="table-cell">{{input.comments}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbju6Lb6/1/)

Issue is the display:flex attribute in your html :

```
<div class="table-cell" style="display:flex;align-items:center;min-width: 180px;max-width:180px;">Type</div>
```

Min-width is still applied, and table's behaviour is back to normal.